# Positioning - Why does it mess up the resolution?

Tags: html, css, positioning

I've tried changing the pixels to percentages and nothing seems to work. If I make it in 1920x1080 and then switch to a lower resolution the website looks all cluttered and weird.

Here's the CSS code:

```
body
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: url("images/Background.png")
}

#header
{
    position: absolute;
    top: -160;
    left: 420;
    right: 0;
}

.headerImage1 
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Here is what it looks like on a different resolution: (The correct way would be centered)

http://puu.sh/6RgHg.jpg

EDIT: HTML part:

```
<body>
<div id="header">
    <div class="headerImage1">
        <img src="images/Header.png">
    </div>
```

Comment: Please include relevant parts of your HTML.

Comment: Well, you have set the width to 100%.  What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to position it in the center top of the page. Like such: http://puu.sh/6RjFr.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's cause your ratio gets off when you use:

```
width:100%;
height:100%;
```

Try this instead:

```
width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

That way the ration doesn't mess up, if you want the background to not mess up, try this:

```
background: url("images/Background.png") no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

#### EDIT:

If you mean centering the image, absolute poitioning is the absolute size of the browser, the full screen. While relative is the current position of the brower.
I would use relative for cross-device purposes.

Comment: I tried changing it to, "auto;". The page looks exactly the same and nothing changes.

Comment: Can you please tell me the issue again? I do not really understand the issue.

Comment: You want it centered? `width: 95%; height: auto; margin-left: 2.5; margin-right: 2.5;` or `text-align: center;`

Comment: When I look at the website with the coding above it looks perfectly fine and positioned correctly on my 1920x1080 monitor. When I change resolutions to something smaller, the image goes all the way over to the right side of the page instead of the middle where it's supposed to be.

Comment: Ahh, that is cause absolute is the absolute size of the screen, not the browser window. I would use relative positioning.